# Android Telephony CellSignalStrength

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telephonymanager

sorry for my bad english.

I want to ask about android telephony : CellSignalStrength

I have code like below to display signal strength information on android..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private TextView textView2;

public String gsmStrength;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);



    try {

        for (CellInfo info : tm.getAllCellInfo()) {
            if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                // do what you need
                gsmStrength = String.valueOf(gsm.getDbm());
            } else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                CellSignalStrengthCdma cdma = ((CellInfoCdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                gsmStrength = String.valueOf(cdma.getDbm());
            } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                gsmStrength = String.valueOf(lte.getDbm());
            } else {
                gsmStrength = String.valueOf("UNknown");
            }

        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 3: " + e);
    }

    textView2.setText(gsmStrength.toString());
```

when I run it shows the result is -93

so what I want is the result in the form of a string with what information it is:
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR

like the picture below:
[image]

**not the number -93 earlier**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `getDbm()` which return the "signal strength as dBm" you should use `getLevel()`

> Retrieve an abstract level value for the overall signal quality.
> Returns int value between SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN and SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT inclusive

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthGsm#getLevel()

So you get one of the int values from [CellSignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength):

```
CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD
CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT
CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE
CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN
CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR
```

If you still want to get a string instead of the int you can use

```
public static String getLevelString(int level) {
    switch(level) {
        case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD:
            return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD";
        case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT:
            return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT";
        case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE:
            return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE";
        case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN:
            return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN";
        case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR:
            return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR";
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported level " + level);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, after I changed from getdbm to getlevel, the result is 3

then how to become
SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD
etc

Comment: @MathewsEdward Please look at the end of my answer, there you will find the function that converts the int level to the string you want.

Comment: like this?

sorry I'm really just learning

Comment: ` public static String getLevelString(int gsmString) { 
        switch(gsmString) {
            case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD:
                return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD";
            case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT:
                return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT";
            case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE:
                return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE";
            case CellSignalStrength.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN:
                return "SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN";

Comment: @MathewsEdward Not sure what your latest comment means. But naming an int `gsmString` is a bad idea.

Comment: So how?
please help me, how to get it to display in the textview

Comment: @MathewsEdward Just copy and use the method I have provided in my answer. The code in your comment looks very similar (as far as I can see because of the missing formatting) but misses the default case and has the wrong variable naming (minor issue).

Comment: okay,
Is this true?

 public static String getLevelString(int level) {
        switch(level) {

I changed to

 public static String getLevelString(int gsmStrength) {
        switch(gsmStrength) {

Comment: because if I run this, the result is still "3"

Comment: Please just add my provided method to your MainActivity class and call `gsmStrength = getLevelString(gsm.getLevel());` and you have your string

Comment: thank you thank you thank you so mucccchhh... you saved my day.

anyway, do you know about android telephony datafailcause?